# How to get the day of the year [1-365|366] with Luxon?

Tags: javascript, datetime, luxon

Is it possible to get **the day of the year** in the `1-365|366` range from a [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) `DateTime` object?

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve computing the value. So something similar to `DateTime.day`, `DateTime.weekNumber`, `DateTime.month` etc. or using `DateTime.toFormat()` would be awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Luxon, you can simply use [`ordinal`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeordinal):

> Get the ordinal (meaning the day of the year)

Example:

```js
console.log(luxon.DateTime.now().ordinal)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.0.3/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That didnt't cross my eye while browsing the docs.